# Type Resolution on a instances of namespaced classes

Tags: typescript

Let say somewhere in the code we have namespace, created by export-import routine.

```js
namespace ClassCollection {
  export class Test1 {
    public Method1() { return 1; }
  }
  export class Test2 {
    public Method2() { return 2; }
  }
}
```

Somewhere else, let say in the main module, we want to define variable that would represent the dictionary of instances of those classes. It meant to be made automatically through cycling through namespace elements, but at the end would looks something like this:

```js
const collection = {
  Test1: new ClassCollection.Test1,
  Test2: new ClassCollection.Test2,
}

// to be accessible like this
collection.Test1.Method1();
collection.Test2.Method2();
```

It's easily solvable for each class separately, like this:

```js
const Test1: InstanceType<(typeof ClassCollection)["Test1"]> 
  = new ClassCollection.Test1;
const Test2: InstanceType<(typeof ClassCollection)["Test2"]> 
  = new ClassCollection.Test2;

Test1.Method1();
Test2.Method2();
```

But how to make generic type resolution for that? My best try is:

```js
type TypeResolution<T> = {
  [C in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[C]>;
};

/** won't work because of: 
 * Type 'T[C]' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'.
 */
const collection: TypeResolution<typeof ClassCollection> = {
  Test1: new ClassCollection.Test1,
  Test2: new ClassCollection.Test2,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that `T[C]` cannot be verified to represent a constructor, so TypeScript can't guarantee that it can infer the instance type of all of the properties in the `ClassCollection` namespace.

You can tell TypeScript that all properties do in fact represent a constructor, by including a type constraint on the generic type parameter `T`:

```js
type TypeResolution<T extends Record<string, { new (...args: any[]): any }>> = {
  [C in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[C]>;
};
```

Now you give the compiler enough info for it to compute the instance type, [and it all works correctly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhANiKUUHs1ongBcBLHYJAbwFgAoJJCADxhwCcil4MskAVaEQCMVOgwYwArgCM0JeEgCyEIgAscAEyEAKAJRUkbFZLYUhAbiQBfMddvNWHLjyj9BAJlH1xU2fKUq6hruegZGRCYU7pY23rGxdEQAnjDIfCkQAErQeJKk5AA8fIxMRBDAGq7Z8OwaBVBEbCTAAOYANAbAEADuSNoAdIMgbC1QAFxIIMBJANoAuroTU0nWAHyrSAC8XgwzKEjNSADWEEk4AGb8cxMAksANU4jpqUV7c6vmdFaftHQ195wavhCPlgBNnlkcmg8mRgAVkqkLqgXLhgcRYRttjRvAIGkIJl1euhMNg8AR0eR+rjhG1bNT3ASesiSajyaCqR5abRvnQ-mSQbCOXj+so1JoLHy0ez6SLAppokA).